# Get data from a request on cy.wait from cypress. Javascript variables scope

Tags: javascript, cypress

I believe this a stupid question? It seems that it should be easy to do haha.

```
cy.wait(['@purchase']).then((interception) => {
    contractId = interception[0].request.body.contract;
});
```

How can I access that contractId variable from outside ".then"? How should I define it? I don't know much of javascript. Right now it says that "contractId is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define it first!

```js
let contractId;

cy.wait(['@purchase']).then((interception) => {
  contractId = interception[0].request.body.contract;    // called "closure"
});
```

But what do you want to do with it? Cypress likes to "chain" things, so you could return it from the `.then()` callback to use it

```js
cy.wait(['@purchase']).then((interception) => {
  const contractId = interception[0].request.body.contract;
  return contractId;
})
.should('not.eq', 0);                                  // gets passed the contractId
```

So, visiting the contract,

```js
cy.wait(['@purchase']).then((interception) => {
  const contractId = interception[0].request.body.contract;  
  return contractId;
}).then(coontractId => {
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl') + "/contracts/" + contractId) 
})
```

or

```js
cy.wait(['@purchase']).then((interception) => {
  const contractId = interception[0].request.body.contract;
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl') + "/contracts/" + contractId);
})
```

With an alias (within the same test, because aliases are cleared between tests)

```js
cy.wait(['@purchase']).then((interception) => {
  const contractId = interception[0].request.body.contract;
  return contractId;
})
.as('contractId');

// some more stuff before using contractId...

cy.get('@contractId').then(contractId => {
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl') + "/contracts/" + contractId);
})
```

Comment: I want to use it to address the browser to that created contract something like: cy.visit("http://domain/contracts/" + contractId)

Comment: I see, so I did ok the first time, but for some reason the console is just giving me the "undefined" at the beginning and not the contractId.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that I don't want to do it at that step, I have to check many other things first. That's why I thought I needed to save the variable.

Comment: Or Cypress gives you aliases which can preserve the value, will add one more example.